# Diagonalization of Leslie matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

I am trying to show that this matrix:

$$L=\begin{bmatrix}
 f_0 &  f_1& \cdot & \cdot & f_n\\
p_0 &  0 & \cdot & \cdot & 0\\
0 &  p_1& \cdot & \cdot & 0\\
\cdot &  \cdot& \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\\
0 &  0& \cdot & p_{n-1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}\mbox{  , } 0\leq f_i \mbox{ and }0<p_i<1.$$

commonly known as the Leslie matrix is diagonalizable.

I know a $n \times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if there exist $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. I also know two different eigenvalues have linearly independent eigenvectors. So my approach was to show the characteristic equation of the Leslie matrix has $n$ different solutions, but here I got stuck.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: This looks like a fun enough problem but I think it would help if you translated it into general mathematical terms on top of your description of the context. Context is good but what I gather you're attempting is to show that a polynomial in the form

$\lambda^n - s_0 b_1 \lambda^{n-1} - s_0 s_1 b_2 \lambda^{n-2} - s_0 s_1 s_3 b_3 \lambda^{n-3} - ... - s_0 \cdots s_{n_1}b_n \lambda - $

has no double roots? (where $s_i, b_i$ are positive numbers satisfying some crteria?)

Or in bastard shorthand

$\lambda^n - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}s_{(k-1)!}b_k \lambda^{n - k} = 0$

(Just speculation!)

Comment: Or provided some links in case wikipedia isn't in correspondence with your definition.

Comment: "the" Leslie matrix or "a'' Leslie matrix ?

Comment: @Squid Very thorough remark thats sounds like a generalization of companion matrix determinant (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple counterexample with a $3 \times 3$ matrix:

$$L=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  5&   3\\
 1 &   0&   0\\
 0 &   1&   0
\end{bmatrix}$$

with eigenvalues $-1$ (order of multiplicity $2$) and $3$.

The eigenspace associated with eigenvalue $-1$ is obtained as solution of

$$\begin{cases}2x&+&5y&+&3z&=&0\\x&+&y&&&=&0\\&&y&+&z&=&0\end{cases}$$

which gives $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} \ = \ k \ \begin{bmatrix}\ \ 1\\-1\\ \ \ 1\end{bmatrix}.$

Thus, this eigenspace is only one dimensional. As this dimension is less than the order of multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue, matrix $L$ is not diagonalizable.

Remark 1: $kL$, with any positive real $k$, is a counterexample as well.

Remark 2: matrix $L$ is a "companion" matrix : see the Wikipedia article (http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/watkins/seminar/pdfiles/fiedler_companion.pdf) where it is explicitly said: "In general, the companion matrix may be non-diagonalizable.". But the difficulty is to find such a matrix with **positive** coefficients.

Remark 3: a companion matrix can have different equivalent forms: one can find the (opposite of the) list of polynomial coefficients on

- the rightmost column (as in the Wikipedia article)
- upper row (in direct correspondence with Leslie matrices, as the convention taken in Matlab (https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/compan.html)),
- bottom row.

Remark 4: the counterexample given by @quasi is, up to a multiplication by 2 (which does not affect the "non-diagonalizability" property), a "companion matrix".

If you are interested by companion matrices, here is a very interesting discussion by Cleve Moler, the founder of Matlab: (http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/12/23/fiedler-companion-matrix/)